# Cannot see table content in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I create a database to save my users information. But I can only see the content of password part, and I can't see other parts content like email, username, first name etc. I put here a screenshot and my php codes thank you all.[image]

```
    <?php
session_start();

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "register_user");

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    session_start();
    $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["firstname"]);
    $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lastname"]);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
    $password_2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password_2"]);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
    $email_2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email_2"]);

    if ($password == $password_2) {

        $password = md5($password);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user_data(firstname, lastname, username, password, email) VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$password', '$email')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $_SESSION['message'] = "You logged successfully";
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("location: index.html");
    }else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Passwords don't match";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: ***Please*** don't store raw passwords in your database.

Comment: shmosel, thank you, I am new in PHP. I will learn bullet points day by day.

Comment: I just noticed you *are* actually hashing the password. That's good, but MD5 is not considered a secure hash and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysqli please use

```
mysqli_real_escape_string(connection,escapestring);
```

Hope it helps.

Plus you need not to start the session twice you can use it once